Плавная анимация, не привязанная ни к чему


let i = 1, 
  interval = 500,
  shag = 22;

setInterval(_ => {
  i++;
  document.querySelector('div.cc').style.width = ((i * shag) > 100 ? 100 : (i * shag)) + '%'
}, interval);
div {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 0px;
}
<div class='cc'></div>



Создал пример, где interval и shag могут принимать разные значения.
Максимальная ширина 100%, минимальная 0%
Ищу решение при котором будут плавная анимация но в тоже время будет успевать за таймингом.
В примере, на подобии ползунка к видео, где ширина привязана к таймингу.
Ищу решение только за счет css, ничего не придумал, все что пробовал. Все не то...

Возможно ошибаюсь, но что если интервал будет 1 сек, а шаг может быть любым. Может 50% за раз, может 1 и менее за раз. Быть может есть решение когда интервал в 1 секунду.

Главное, что скорость анимации адаптировалась,  была плавность, не анимация отрезками...

Было бы здорово, если есть решение, при интервале любом и при шаге любом, анимация работала должным образом.

"Ищу решение при котором будут плавная анимация но в тоже время будет успевать за таймингом" — у вас проблема в том, что анимация не поспевает за таймингом? По тексту вопроса (особенно по заголовку) не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите

Ищу решение только за счет css эм... может @keyframes? transition?

Много раз пробовал то и другое, не выходило. Анимация есть, но по-прежнему просматривались шаги, интервалы... Может у вас что получиться?

Возможно передать текущую ширину ползунка и ширину к которой необходимо привести. Каждый раз, когда тайм видео меняется. Что то подсказывает, что и это не поможет.

Ну а что здесь сложного? Вам нужно чтобы CSS анимация была по времени равна интервалу.


let i = 1,
  interval = 500,
  shag = 22;

document.querySelector('div.cc').style.animationDuration = interval + 'ms';

setInterval(_ => {
  i++;
  /*
  document.querySelector('div.cc').style.width = ((i * shag) > 100 ? 100 : (i * shag)) + '%'
  */
}, interval);
div {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 0px;
  animation: anim 500ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<div class='cc'></div>




Ну раз вы решили стилями через js сделать, то у стилей есть такая хорошая штука - transition


let i = 1, 
  interval = 500,
  shag = 22;

setInterval(_ => {
  i++;
  document.querySelector('div.cc').style
    .width = ((i * shag) > 100 ? 100 : (i * shag)) + '%'
}, interval);
div {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 0px;
  transition: 1s;
}
<div class='cc'></div>




Скорее всего, я опоздал плюс-минус на месяц.
Но тут не было ответа с Web Animation API.
А между прочим, решение требует гораздо меньших изменений в исходном коде автора.


let interval = 500,
  shag = 22;

document.querySelector(".cc").animate(
  [
    { width: "0px" },
    { width: "calc( 100dvw - 2rem )" },
  ],
  {
    duration: interval * shag,
    iterations: Infinity,
  },
);
div {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
}
<div class='cc'></div>



